# Find the element that appears exactly thrice

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview recently.

Given an int array where all but one numbers appear once and exactly one number appears 3 times. Find that number in  O(1) space and O(n) time complexity.

How do i approach this question?

Comment: Are there any constraints on what integers may appear in the array?

Comment: Are you allowed to mutate the input?

Comment: Integers are positive, no other constraints.

Comment: Yes, as long as you satisfy the space and time complexity.

Comment: If its of any help, I was also given a hint where i was asked to try implementing my own xor function.

Comment: Interesting. I've heard he famous interview problem where all of the numbers appear three times, except one that appears once. Answers to that question are plentiful online....maybe you could tweak a solution to that problem to solve the problem you are given.

Comment: Any interviewer that uses an interview question like this is more interested in proving his own superiority over the candidate than he is in finding out whether the candidate is any good.  That's a pretty good piece of evidence that this isn't somewhere that you want to work.

Comment: @user2980096 Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260232/algorithm-to-find-a-duplicate-entry-in-constant-space-and-on-time?noredirect=1&lq=1) link? I do not read it carefully but it shows an lower bound to find duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

Simply sort the array and find the answer.

**Note:** Since the array has integer values you can use [Radix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) sort algorithm which has linear time-complexity. Moreover, you can use it as an in-place algorithm.

PS: The *thrice* is the illusion data and the original problem was the interviewee can think as simple as sorting problem. How much this expectation is fair is respect to the level of interview!