# Java: Interleaving multiple arrays into a single array

Tags: java, arraylist

I found [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860490/interleaving-multiple-arrays-into-a-single-array) question about interleaving two arraylists into one, but its in PHP. I was asked this question in interview as well but could'nt solve it, came back to SO to look if it was addressed already, but i could only find this  [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1598)

So any pointers to pseudo code or method definition ?

Big(O) restrictions : O(n) - time cost and O(1) - space cost

> **Example:**
>       a[]= a1, a2, ..., an
>       b[]= b1, b2, ..., bn
>   Rearrange the arraylist to a1, b1, a2, b2, ..., an, bn

**Editv1.0** : Arraylists a[] and b[] are of same size

**Editv2.0** : What if the question is extended to rearrange in one of given two arrays, but not create a new array ?

Comment: Does "`O(1)` space cost" mean "`O(1)` _in addition_ to the space needed to store the two arrays?" What is the expected behavior when the two arrays are not the same size?

Comment: @Matt Yes ur right, Edited my question about arrays size.

Comment: Oh, btw, that paper has basically nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Well it was attached in one of the similar questions, but the issue was to reaarange within the given 2 arrays but not create a new array.

Comment: You are using the terms array and arraylist interchangeably, and both answers so far deal with arrays. Which structure did the question ask about?

Comment: If we have one array [a1 a2 ... an b1 b2 .. bn] instead of two, I believe the paper is relevant.  OR even if the resulting interleaving is supposed to look like a = [a1 b1 a2 b2 ...a(n/2) b(n/2)], b = [ a(n/2+1) b(n/2+1) ... an bn].

Comment: Found an old stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777901/array-interleaving-problem

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 there is no proper implementation in that question

Comment: @mccarthy  its arraylist

Comment: @SuperMan: Your question is contradictory. You want to rearrange in one array but only use O(1) space? Are you sure about your question?

Comment: Yes I'm sure about O(1) space

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For simplicity, assume that the arrays are the same length, and are `int` arrays.

```
int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b)
{
    assert (a.length == b.length);

    int[] result = new int[a.length + b.length];

    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        result[i*2] = a[i];
        result[i*2+1] = b[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Matt That is true, But what if i had to merge into one of the two arrays, but not create a new array ?

Comment: You can't do that unless you're willing to exclude half of the elements in each input array, because arrays cannot be resized.

Comment: @Matt You have arraylists in Java , which can help us to increase the size?

Comment: Yes, but that's a list, not an array, and I'd have used completely different code in that case.

Comment: Aahh, I have tagged the question under Java thought u would consider lists buy default..

Comment: @SuperMan maybe you could stick half the interleaved elements in one of the original arrays and half the interleaved elements in the other original array, but I don't see how that could be done in O(n).

Comment: @mlaw: with arrays that's actually pretty easy, it's just a matter of swapping elements between the two arrays.

Comment: @Matt That is what I thought, at first. But it doesn't seem to be the case. interleaving [1 2 3 4 5] and [6 7 8 9 0]: you would first start with replacing 2 with 6 leads to replacing 3 with 2 and 5 with 3 and 9 with 5 and so on. Then you need to replace 4 with 7 and propagate those replaces.

Comment: @mlaw care to post your ideas as answer ?

Comment: @mlaw it depends on the exact interleaving you're aiming for in the second array. To interleave the two arrays `x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `y = [a, b, c, d, e]` you could create `x' = [1, b, 3, d, 5]` and `y' = [a, 2, c, 4, d]`. See what I mean?

Comment: @Matt Yeah, in that case it would be straightforward.

Comment: @Matt: Creating x' and y' is not O(1) space, is it? I agree with mlaw. Without creating new arrays/extending the original ones, it seems hard. The paper linked in the question might be useful there.

Comment: @user: `x'` and `y'` wouldn't actually be new arrays, I used the "prime" to indicate that they were modified versions of the original.

Comment: @Matt: Then how would you do the swapping? Care to elaborate? Pick arrays of 12 elements each for example. Remember the O(1) extra memory constraint. Note: I am talking about x' = [1 a 2 b 3], y' = [c 4 d 5 e]. (I just realized you are talking about a different interleaving, sorry about that).

Comment: btw, I see no point in interleaving as you did :-) Why not just leave the arrays as they are?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not doable with your given constraints (`O(n)` time and `O(1)` space, i.e. no additional space) for an array or array-based list. (Assuming of course, that we can't simply create a new List object delegating to the original ones.)

If you have two linked lists, this is doable - if we assume the garbage collector is fast enough, i.e. deleting an element from one list and adding it to another list does not violate the space limitation.

```
public <X> void interleaveLists(List<X> first, List<X> second)
{
    ListIterator<X> firstIt = first.listIterator();
    ListIterator<X> secondIt = second.listIterator();
    while(secondIt.hasNext()) {
        fistIt.next();
        firstIt.add(secondIt.next());
        secondIt.remove();
    }
}
```

This method works for any pair of lists, but is only O(n) for linked lists.

For a custom linked list where we can modify the pointers, we don't have to rely on the garbage collector, we would simply change the nodes. Here for a singly-linked list:

```
public void interleaveLinkedLists(Node<X> firstList, Node<X> secondList) {
    while(secondList != null) {
        Node<X> nextFirst = firstList.next;
        Node<X> nextSecond = secondList.next;
        firstList.next = secondList;
        secondList.next = nextFirst;
        firstList = nextFirst;
        secondList = nextSecond;
    }
}
```

For a doubly-linked list, we would also have to adapt the prev-pointers.

Here the wrapping variant mentioned in the first paragraph:

```
public List<X> interleaveLists(final List<X> first, final List<X> second)
{
   if (first.size() != second.size())
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   return new AbstractList<X>() {
      public int size() {
         return 2 * first.size();
      }
      public X get(int index) {
         return index % 2 == 0 ? first.get(index / 2) : second.get(index / 2);
      }
      // if necessary, add a similar set() method.  add/remove are not sensible here.
   };
}
```

This is actually `O(1)` in time, too.

Answer (score 2):

I've done up a small solution going on the assumption that you are talking about using the `ArrayList` (see my comment on the question). I may be oversimplifying the problem based on some of the responses here, but here goes anyway.

The below example takes a and b both of type `ArrayList<Integer>` and interleaves them by inserting b[0] after a[0], b[1] after a[1] etc. This snippet of course naively assumes that a and b are of the same size as per your Edit v1.0. It also does not create a new `ArrayList` as per your Edit v2.0.

```
//a and b are of type ArrayList<Integer>
for (int i = a.size(); i > 0; i--)
{
    a.add(i, b.get(i - 1));
}
```

No matter what happens if you are combining the ArrayLists you're going to have twice the size.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mod (%) operations in Matt's answer are incorrect. Under the same assumption (that the arrays are the same length), I'd propose the following solution instead:

```
static int[] merge(final int[] a, final int[] b)
{
    final int[] result = new int[a.length * 2];

    for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        result[i << 1] = a[i];
        result[(i << 1) + 1] = b[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

I tested (very briefly), and it appears to work, but of course makes no attempt to handle error conditions such as null arguments or input arrays mismatched in size.

Comment: Oops - looks like Matt fixed his example too. They're essentially equivalent now.

Answer (score 0):

*in the meantime lambda was introduced*
O(n) time complexity
O(1) space complexity

```
int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) {
    return( IntStream.range( 0, a.length ).flatMap(
        n -> IntStream.of( a[n], b[n] ) ).toArray() );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The lists don't have to be the same size:

```
public class InterleaveTwoLists<X> {

    public List<X> interleaveLists(final List<X> first, final List<X> second) {

        return new AbstractList<X>() {
            private int minSize;
            private int combinedMinSize;
            private int size;
            private List<X>largerList;
            {{
                minSize = Math.min(first.size(), second.size());
                combinedMinSize = minSize*2;
                size = first.size() + second.size();
                largerList = first.size() > minSize ? first : second;
            }}

            public int size() {
                return size;
            }

            public X get(int index) {
                if (index < combinedMinSize) {
                    return index % 2 == 0 
                        ? first.get(index / 2) 
                        : second.get(index / 2);
                }
                else { 
                    return largerList.get(index-minSize);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

To test this:

```
public class InterleaveTwoListsTest {

    private static final Logger log = 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(InterleaveTwoListsTest.class);

    List<String> first = new ArrayList<String>() {
    { 
        add("one"); add("three"); add("five"); 
        add("seven"); add("eight"); add("nine");
    }};

    List<String> second = new ArrayList<String>() {
    { 
        add("two"); add("four"); add("six"); 
    }};


    private InterleaveTwoLists<String> interleaveTwoLists;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        interleaveTwoLists = new InterleaveTwoLists<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<String> combinedList = interleaveTwoLists.interleaveLists(first, second);
        for( int i = 0; i < first.size() + second.size(); i++) { 
            log.debug("{}: {}", i, combinedList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I find your lack of assertion statements disturbing.

Comment: Huh? Are you referring to JUnit assert statements? These are "tests" meant to demonstrate. Do you really use "main()" methods when you want to demonstrate? -1 on that.

Comment: I don't use tests to demonstrate; I assert behavior about them instead.  In a sense, the tests do demonstrate whether or not my assertions are valid.  But a JUnit test without any assertions is...disturbing.