# Determine if two arrays are identical up to permutation?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if array B is a permutation of A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639661/check-if-array-b-is-a-permutation-of-a)

Is there a way to tell if two arrays of numbers (which can contain positives, negatives or repeats) are permutations of each other in `O(n)` time complexity and `O(1)` space complexity? I could not solve it because of tight space constraints.

Comment: Are they arrays of fixed-length integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers are integers - [in-place radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#In-place_MSD_radix_sort_implementations) can give you `O(nlogk)` time, where `k` is the range of the numbers, and `n` is the number of elements. 

Note that the algorithm requires `O(logk)` space, for the stack trace of recursive calls.

If you can bound `k` to a constant (2^64 for example) - you get `O(n)` time with `O(1)` space.

After sorting - you can simply iterate on both arrays and check if they are identical.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done if you have a hard limit on the range of the numbers themselves.

Say for example you know that you have two arrays A and B and that the numbers are bound between -128 and +127(8bit signed). You simply have an array of 256 locations. Each number `n` would map to the location `n + 128`.

You iterate over both arrays, for array A you would increment the corresponding location, for array B you decrement. Then you check if all locations are 0 or not. If they are, the arrays are permutations, if not, they aren't.

The time complexity is `O(n+k)`. The space complexity is `O(k)` where `k` is the range of the numbers. Since `k` is independent of `n`, so that's `O(n)` and `O(1)` as far as `n` is concerned and as long as you have a bound on `k`.

Note also that the time complexity can be further reduced to simply `O(n)` instead of `O(n+k)`. You simply keep a running total of numbers that have non-zero counts. Every time an increment/decrement would push a count from to something else, you increment the running total. Every time it would be pushed *to* zero, you decrement the total. At the end, if the total is 0, then all counts are 0.

Edit: Amit's answer probably has a better space complexity though :)

PS: However, this algorithm can be applied if the arrays of numbers are streamed in, so they never actually have to be all kept in memory. So it might have a smaller space complexity than outright sorting *if* the conditions are right

Comment: Using a hash map rather then a fixed size array can bring the space requirement down to `O(min{k,n})`, using the same approach.

Comment: Yep, both are true, that was just an example. Also, amit's suggestion is the general case of that. `(add 128)` can be a hash function itself. So the general case is to just use a hashmap.