# Determine If An Array of Length N is in an Array of Length M

Tags: java, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to determine if array contains n…n+m?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177118/algorithm-to-determine-if-array-contains-n-nm)

Lets assume that M > N, and you have 2 arrays. One of length M called A and one of length N called B. Is there a faster way to find out if array B exists in array A?

For Example:

A = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]

B1 = [ 2 3 4 ]

so array B1 exists in A while something like [ 1 3 2 ] does not.

This is essentially implementing something like isSubstring() in Java with a char array.

The only method that I can think of is in O(n^2) where you compare each element in A with the initial element in B and iterate through B looking for a match.

I guess this question is fairly common in interviews, so my question is asking if there is a faster approach.

Comment: @Rotsor. Posted that at wrong place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)

> algorithm kmp_search:
>       input:
>           an array of characters, S (the text to be searched)
>           an array of characters, W (the word sought)
>       output:
>           an integer (the zero-based position in S at which W is found)
>
> ```
> define variables:
>     an integer, m ← 0 (the beginning of the current match in S)
>     an integer, i ← 0 (the position of the current character in W)
>     an array of integers, T (the table, computed elsewhere)
>
> while m+i is less than the length of S, do:
>     if W[i] = S[m + i],
>         if i equals the (length of W)-1,
>             return m
>         let i ← i + 1
>     otherwise,
>         let m ← m + i - T[i],
>         if T[i] is greater than -1,
>             let i ← T[i]
>         else
>             let i ← 0
>
> (if we reach here, we have searched all of S unsuccessfully)
> return the length of S
> ```

Complexity:

> Assuming the prior existence of the table T, the search portion of the
>   Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm has complexity O(k), where k is the
>   length of S and the O is big-O notation. As except for the fixed
>   overhead incurred in entering and exiting the function, all the
>   computations are performed in the while loop, we will calculate a
>   bound on the number of iterations of this loop; in order to do this we
>   first make a key observation about the nature of T. By definition it
>   is constructed so that if a match which had begun at S[m] fails while
>   comparing S[m + i] to W[i], then the next possible match must begin at
>   S[m + (i - T[i])]. In particular the next possible match must occur at
>   a higher index than m, so that T[i] < i. Using this fact, we will show
>   that the loop can execute at most 2k times. For in each iteration, it
>   executes one of the two branches in the loop. The first branch
>   invariably increases i and does not change m, so that the index m + i
>   of the currently scrutinized character of S is increased. The second
>   branch adds i - T[i] to m, and as we have seen, this is always a
>   positive number. Thus the location m of the beginning of the current
>   potential match is increased. Now, the loop ends if m + i = k;
>   therefore each branch of the loop can be reached at most k times,
>   since they respectively increase either m + i or m, and m ≤ m + i: if
>   m = k, then certainly m + i ≥ k, so that since it increases by unit
>   increments at most, we must have had m + i = k at some point in the
>   past, and therefore either way we would be done. Thus the loop
>   executes at most 2k times, showing that the time complexity of the
>   search algorithm is O(k).

additional information:

Efficiency of the KMP algorithm

> Since the two portions of the algorithm have, respectively,
>   complexities of O(k) and O(n), the complexity of the overall algorithm
>   is O(n + k). These complexities are the same, no matter how many
>   repetitive patterns are in W or S.